# How to create Assessments in InfoPath 2013

Tags: infopath

We have a task, we need to create Assessment using InfoPath in SharePoint 2013.

New to use InfoPath so can you please suggest me how I should work on this.

Queries:

1. Where we have to save the Answer to validate (I had create a form in that I had written 2 question and used radio button), on submit button I had set the conditions "But I know this is wrong format because the validation of the answer can't be set on the button"
2. On the click of the submit button how we can display certificate and data should be pulling from the user list and also then the scores should save in a particular library as the user has completed this Assessment.

Thanks in Advance